# Exposing an apache port 80 that is in an office behind a firewall?

Tags: apache-2.2, security, firewall

I have a box which is on the network in the office, and people can access my apache server that is running when the people are on the network.

What do I have to do to enable people from outside our office (lets say some clients, or even me at home) to be able to get to the instance of apache which is running on my box?

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: What model router does the office use? That will determine if we can answer it here, or if the great people over at Super User will be able to answer it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general terms you should at your office's router or firewall add a static NAT to map an internet public address to the internal IP address of your web server.

Then you should allow traffic to port 80/443/other on your public IP address to the range of IP address you want to provide this access to (assuming it is not the whole Internet).

Or you could have your clients (and/or you) connect via VPN (IPSec/SSL/L2TP) to your office and then to your server.

Not knowing what kind of firewall/router and network topology you have makes it difficult to give more detailed instructions.

Anyways, regardless of the kind of hardware you have, it is not a good security practice to allow access from outside your network to resources on your internal network. There maybe misconfiguration/bugs on your web server or on the applications that are running on top of it and this may jeopardize the security of your server and by cause and effect, of your internal network. This is what [DMZs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMZ_%28computing%29) are good for.